# How to set the line break in Xcode label?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode

I want to ask an stupid question about the Xcode. I use the .xib to add a Label to my interface and I type something in the Label. For example, Hello World. How can I set the 2 words or 3 words in different lines?

Example:

Hello World  // I don't want this

Hello // this is correct

World

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about a Cocoa xib, not a Carbon xib.  Draw a "multi-line label" item from the library palette into your window, and then you can get multiple lines by word wrapping.  If you want a hard line break, type option-return while editing the text.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am using the Cocoa Touch in the Library. And where is the 'multi-line label?

Comment: Since you only said "Xcode", I was assuming Mac OS X.  Cocoa Touch (same as iPhone SDK?) may have different UI widgets.

Comment: P.S. I added the cocoa-touch tag.

Comment: thank you for you reply. Ya, I am writing the iPhone application. Can it also do it as the same?

Comment: If you are using Xcode4, you can set number of lines of label to get a multiline label. Just add a label, then in the Attributes Inspector, set the number of lines you want. If you want a spesific line break, option+return works in the text of label.

Comment: If setting the text programmatically, how do you type "option-return"?

Comment: @PeterAjtai: Programmatically, just include `\n` in a string literal.

Comment: @JWWalker - I tried that, and it just printed a the literal character `\n`... though my string is coming from another file, so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @PeterAjtai: Maybe you should post your own question and give more detail.

Comment: @JWWalker - Thanks, I might. I worked around it by dynamically setting the width to where I wanted the line breaks, and just letting it wrap.

Comment: Great! option-return is what I'm looking for